# oracle11g sql: Warning: Type created with compilation errors

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to create a supertype customer service and subtype agent and supervisor, so they can inherent values however when I try to run this in oracle sql: a message comes up

`Warning: Type created with compilation errors.`

What is wrong with the code below?

```
Create or replace type customer_s_type as object (
   csID number, 
   csName varchar(15),
   csType number ) NOT FINAL;

Create or replace type supervisor_type UNDER customer_s_type ( title varchar (10) );  

Create or replace type agent_type UNDER customer_s_type (title varchar (10)); 

Create table supervisor of supervisor_type (
   CONSTRAINT supervisor_PK PRIMARY KEY (csID));

Create table agent of agent_type (CONSTRAINT agent_PK PRIMARY KEY (csID));

create table customer_service(
   csID number(10),
   csType number(10),
   constraint supervisor_pk primary key(csID) );
```

Comment: Your customer_service table has a duplicate constraint name, but other than that there doesn't seem to be anything wrong. See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f3996). Also, please use the excellent formatting tools for code. It makes it so much more interesting for the reader.

Comment: What does `show errors` give you?

Comment: the error was: Warning: Type created with compilation errors. As you suggested the customer_service table need to be changed for constraint supervisor_pk primary key(csID) );  and also need the / to separate command as suggested for the user below ' Alex Poole'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `show errors` in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer, or `select * from user_errors`, to see the error details.

Since you've shown six commands and the warning is about one of the first three (since it refers to `type`), and they appear OK independently apart from the constraint pointed put in comments, it looks like the whole script is being imterpreted as one command. It depends on your client settings, but you probably just need to seperate the commands with a `/` to cause them to execute. Becuase types can include PL/SQL the `;` isn't treated as a statement seperator. So:

```
Create or replace type customer_s_type as object (
   csID number, 
   csName varchar(15),
   csType number ) NOT FINAL;
/

Create or replace type supervisor_type UNDER customer_s_type ( title varchar (10) );
/

Create or replace type agent_type UNDER customer_s_type (title varchar (10));
/

Create table supervisor of supervisor_type (
   CONSTRAINT supervisor_PK PRIMARY KEY (csID));

Create table agent of agent_type (CONSTRAINT agent_PK PRIMARY KEY (csID));

create table customer_service(
   csID number(10),
   csType number(10),
   constraint customer_service_pk primary key(csID) );
```

Comment: I had two mistakes as you highlighted  the '/' to separate the commands and the lats line customer_service_pk  primary key. Thank you very much.